# Can I use my UK MAC desktop in the Cayman Islands

Tags: mac

I am moving to the Cayman Islands, which uses the same power source as the US, will I be able to use my MAC desktop there using a US adapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the computer you're using it's hard to say, but probably **Yes**, there should be no problem.

**Most** Apple products have an **auto-switching** power supply which monitors the incoming voltage and automatically switches itself accordingly, **others don't**, and must be changed manually, and others, are regional specific.

[Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1981) you can find a list of the Apple products and whether if they've got this auto-switching *feature*.

Checking your computer's manual should shed some light on this, too.